# Unit Testing Oozie Workflows

Tags: unit-testing, oozie

I am using Oozie as the tool to schedule a lot of my applications on cloudera platform. (spark, MR, Hive, HBase).

One thing which concerns me a lot is that Oozie is a untestable framework.

if I write a workflow using oozie. How do I unit test it?

are there any tools / best practices which allow me to perform an automated unit test on oozie coordinators and workflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MiniOozie](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/ENG_MiniOozie.html) for unit testing of Oozie workflows.

Here is the sample junit test for the oozie workflow :
https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/minitest/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/test/TestWorkflow.java

Comment: Did anyone was able to make it run? Seems like it super coupled with oozie project structure layout and with JUnit TestCase...

Answer (score 0):

There are some gotchas involved in building a test using `MiniOozieTestCase`:

1. Make sure you're using a version of Oozie that includes the fix for [OOZIE-2273](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2273) (fixed in Oozie 4.3.0 but backported to earlier Oozie versions in CDH)
2. Ensure that the login user name does not include a `.`

This is because the regex used to build the proxy user ACL list from the Hadoop configuration is:

```
hadoop\.proxyuser\.[^.]*(\Q.users\E|\Q.groups\E)
```

[DefaultImpersonationProvider.java#L78](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authorize/DefaultImpersonationProvider.java#L78)

If your login username contains a `.` (e.g. `user.name`), you'll get the following error when the test code tries to access HDFS:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: user.name is not allowed to impersonate test
```

In this case, you can override the login username using the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` environment variable or by setting the system property:

```
public class IntTestCustomerModelLoaderJobWorkflow extends MiniOozieTestCase {
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "test");
    }
    ...
}
```

You'll also need to include an `hdfs-site.xml` in the classpath that allows the login user to proxy as the test user.  Example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.test.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
        <description>Allow the superuser test to impersonate any members of any group</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.test.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
        <description>Allow the superuser test to connect from any host to impersonate a user</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

In the example above, the login user is named `test` (the same as the [test user used by `MiniOozieTestCase`](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/release-4.3.1/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/test/XTestCase.java#L505)).  You can use a different username if you like.